# SQL get column values from existing values

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

| Col 1. | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2021 |  |
| Pears | 2021 |  |
| Apple | 2020 | 2 |
| Pears | 2020 | 207 |
| Banana | 2017 | 272 |

I want to fill Col 3 where col 1 have same values

| Col 1. | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2021 | 2 |
| Pears | 2021 | 207 |
| Apple | 2020 | 2 |
| Pears | 2020 | 207 |
| Banana | 2017 | 272 |

I tried self join but that's not working.. Any way I could get this result.

Comment: What if there exists 2 rows with the same `col1` and different `col3`?

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice, assuming you're working with a SQL database. It is unnecessarily complex and generally a waste of storage space. Not to mention, if you want to change something, you'd have to do it multiple times (like you're currently doing, right now.)

Why don't you instead try normalization?

This is a resource for you to start - https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization

For example -

Build 2 separate tables for the two entities; in this case, dates and fruits with corresponding ***Primary Keys*** (**Date_Id** and **Fruit_Id** respectively.)

[image: dates table]
[image: fruits table]

and simply join them with a Junction Table, *referencing* the previously mentioned above ***Primary Keys*** as ***Foreign Keys***

[image: junction table]

If you want to see a full table,  ̷n̷o̷t̷ ̷s̷o̷  simply use the **JOIN** Keyword.

for reference - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
and
https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-join-3-tables-or-more-in-sql/

example -

```
SELECT
  Fruits.Fruit_Name,
  Fruits.Fruit_Amount,
  Dates.Date_Value
FROM Fruits
JOIN Junction_Table
  ON Fruits.Fruit_Id = Junction_Table.Fruit_Id
JOIN Dates
  ON Dates.Date_Id = Junction_Table.Date_Id;
```

Would produce

[image]